# print html table using php dom document

Tags: php, domdocument, dom

Need help,

I would like to print this html code in our web page using php domdocument, but struggling 
I have also write the code with  below. Could you please help me.

```
<table width="610" id="machine" border="0" cellSpacing="10"
    cellPadding="0">

    <TBODY>
        <TR>
            <TD colSpan=2 align=left>
            <DIV id=breadcrumbs><A href="/new-and-used-machinery.php">All
            Machines</A> &nbsp;&gt;&nbsp; <A
                href="/listing.php?cat=Air+Compressors">Air Compressors</A>
            &nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;</DIV>
            <DIV id=ForSale>FOR SALE:</DIV>
            <H1>5 CFM Used Speedaire Air Compressor, Single Phase, 60 Gallon
            tank, 1.5 H.P. #A1194</H1>
            </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD id=photos vAlign=top width=270 align=middle>
            <DIV id=ClickPhotos>Click On Photos For Larger Image:</DIV>
            <!-- PHOTOS DB div style="margin-bottom:12px"><img src="thumb.php?id=A1194.jpg&amp;w=250&amp;h=250"></div --><!-- ORIG PHOTOS div style="margin-bottom:12px"><img src="thumb.php?f=A1194.jpg&amp;w=250&amp;h=250"></div -->
            <DIV style="MARGIN-BOTTOM: 12px"><A
                href="/photos.php?id=7135&amp;p=1"><IMG
                title="Used Speedaire Air Compressor"
                alt="Used Speedaire Air Compressor"
                src="/class/class_Image.php?load=cGhvdG9zL0ExMTk0LmpwZ3wyNTB8MjUwfDF8"></A>
            </DIV>
            <!-- PHOTOS DB div style="margin-bottom:12px"><img src="thumb.php?id=A1194_1.jpg&amp;w=250&amp;h=250"></div --><!-- ORIG PHOTOS div style="margin-bottom:12px"><img src="thumb.php?f=A1194_1.jpg&amp;w=250&amp;h=250"></div -->
            <DIV style="MARGIN-BOTTOM: 12px"><A
                href="/photos.php?id=7135&amp;p=2"><IMG
                title="Used Speedaire Air Compressor"
                alt="Used Speedaire Air Compressor"
                src="/class/class_Image.php?load=cGhvdG9zL0ExMTk0XzEuanBnfDI1MHwyNTB8MXw="></A>
            </DIV>
            </TD>
            <TD id=details vAlign=top width=310 align=left>
            <TABLE
                style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #cdcdcd 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #cdcdcd 1px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 10px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #eee; PADDING-LEFT: 10px; PADDING-RIGHT: 10px; BORDER-TOP: #cdcdcd 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #cdcdcd 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px"
                id=machine_buttons border=0 cellSpacing=3 cellPadding=0>
                <TBODY>
                    <TR>
                        <TD><A onmouseover="swapImg('Manufact', true)"
                            onmouseout="swapImg('Manufact', false)"
                            href="/manufacturer.php?brand=Speedaire"><IMG id=icon_Manufact
                            border=0 alt="" src="/images/machine_button_Manufact.gif"
                            width=66 height=33><BR>
                        Manufacturer Info</A></TD>
                    </TR>
                    <TR>
                        <TD><A onmouseover="swapImg('Category', true)"
                            onmouseout="swapImg('Category', false)"
                            href="/listing.php?cat=Air+Compressors"><IMG id=icon_Category
                            border=0 alt="" src="/images/machine_button_Category.gif"
                            width=66 height=33><BR>
                        Similar Machines</A></TD>
                    </TR>
                    <TR>
                        <TD><A onmouseover="swapImg('Brochure', true)"
                            onmouseout="swapImg('Brochure', false)"
                            href="/manufacturer.php?brand=Speedaire#brochures" target=_blank><IMG
                            id=icon_Brochure border=0 alt=""
                            src="/images/machine_button_Brochure.gif" width=66 height=33><BR>
                        OEM Brochure</A></TD>
                    </TR>
                    <TR>
                        <TD><A style="CURSOR: pointer" id=shadowbox_email class=sb
                            title="Used Speedaire Air Compressor" href="/share.php?id=7135"
                            rel=shadowbox;width=520;height=500 shadowboxCacheKey="1"
                            onMouseOver="swapImg('Email', true)"
                            onMouseOut="swapImg('Email', false)" jQuery1316148993734="2"><IMG
                            id=icon_Email border=0 alt=""
                            src="/images/machine_button_Email.gif" width=66 height=33
                            jQuery1316148993734="3"><BR>
                        Email A Friend</A></TD>
                    </TR>
                    <TR>
                        <TD><A onmouseover="swapImg('Ship', true)"
                            onmouseout="swapImg('Ship', false)" href="/shipping.php?id=7135"><IMG
                            id=icon_Ship border=0 alt=""
                            src="/images/machine_button_Ship.gif" width=66 height=33><BR>
                        Shipping</A></TD>
                    </TR>
                </TBODY>
            </TABLE>
            <DIV id=QuickQuote><A href="/machine-print.php?id=7135" target=_blank><IMG
                title="Print a Quick Quote!" border=0 alt="Print a Quick Quote!"
                align=absMiddle
                src="http://www.sterlingmachinery.com/images/quick_quote.jpg"> </A></DIV>
            <DIV style="MARGIN: 5px 0px 0px 45px">
            <FORM method=post name=addmachine action=/request-quote.php
                jQuery1316148993734="5"><INPUT id=add
                title="Add Machine to Quote Cart" value="Add Machine to Quote Cart"
                alt="Add Machine to Quote Cart"
                src="http://www.sterlingmachinery.com/images/quick_add.jpg"
                type=image name=add jQuery1316148993734="7"> <IMG
                style="DISPLAY: none; CURSOR: pointer" id=remove
                title="Remove from quote cart" name=remove
                alt="Remove from quote cart" src="/images/remove.gif" width=16
                height=16 jQuery1316148993734="8">
            <DIV style="MARGIN-TOP: 5px"><INPUT id=view title="View Quote Cart"
                value="View Quote Cart" alt="View Quote Cart"
                src="http://www.sterlingmachinery.com/images/quick_view.jpg"
                type=image name=view></DIV>
            </FORM>
            </DIV>
            <BR>
            <TABLE id=machine_stats border=0 cellSpacing=5 cellPadding=0
                width=300>
                <TBODY>
                    <TR>
                        <TD class=field vAlign=top align=right>Stock #</TD>
                        <TD vAlign=top align=left>A1194</TD>
                    </TR>
                    <TR>
                        <TD class=field vAlign=top align=right>Manufacturer:</TD>
                        <TD vAlign=top align=left><A
                            href="/manufacturer.php?brand=Speedaire">Speedaire</A></TD>
                    </TR>
                    <TR>
                        <TD class=field vAlign=top align=right>Model:</TD>
                        <TD vAlign=top align=left><A
                            href="/listing.php?cat=Air+Compressors"></A></TD>
                    </TR>
                    <TR>
                        <TD class=field vAlign=top align=right>Capacity:</TD>
                        <TD vAlign=top align=left><A
                            href="/listing.php?cat=Air+Compressors">5 CFM</A></TD>
                    </TR>
                    <TR>
                        <TD class=field vAlign=top align=right>Price:</TD>
                        <TD vAlign=top align=left><SPAN style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffff00">$350</SPAN></TD>
                    </TR>
                    <TR>
                        <TD class=field vAlign=top align=right>Category:</TD>
                        <TD vAlign=top align=left><A
                            href="/results.php?keywords=Air+Compressors">Air Compressors</A></TD>
                    </TR>
                    <TR>
                        <TD class=field vAlign=top align=right>Condition:</TD>
                        <TD vAlign=top align=left>Used Machinery</TD>
                    </TR>
                </TBODY>
            </TABLE>
            <FIELDSET><LEGEND>Full Description</LEGEND>
            <TABLE id=machine_specs border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=4
                width=300>
                <TBODY>
                    <TR>
                        <TD
                            style="BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px"
                            class=field vAlign=top align=right>CFM Rating:</TD>
                        <TD
                            style="BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px"
                            vAlign=top align=left>5</TD>
                    </TR>
                    <TR>
                        <TD class=field vAlign=top align=right>Tank Size:</TD>
                        <TD vAlign=top align=left>60 Gallon</TD>
                    </TR>
                    <TR>
                        <TD class=field vAlign=top align=right>Weight:</TD>
                        <TD vAlign=top align=left>400 LBS.</TD>
                    </TR>
                </TBODY>
            </TABLE>
            </FIELDSET>
            <FIELDSET><LEGEND>Equipped With</LEGEND>Single Phase Motor<BR>
            Horsepower: 1 1/2</FIELDSET>
            <DIV class=privates>* Temporary specifications subject to
            verification.<BR>
            &nbsp; All quotations subject to prior sale.</DIV>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TBODY>

</table>
```

I have write this code but its not getting properly.
Outer foreach loops runs 17 times but should be only two time because the outer table has only two rows.

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->validateOnParse = true;
$xml->loadHTMLFile($url);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);

$table =$xpath->query("//*[@id='machine']")->item(0);

echo "<table border=2>";
$rows = $table->getElementsByTagName("tr");

foreach ($rows as $row) //there i only two rows. 
{
echo "<tr>";
  $cells = $row -> getElementsByTagName('td');

  foreach ($cells as $cell) 
  {
   echo "<td>";
   foreach ($cell->getElementsByTagName('table') as $innerTable )
   {
      foreach ( $innerTable->getElementsByTagName("tr") as $innerTrs)
      {
        foreach ( $innerTrs->getElementsByTagName('td') as $innerCell)
        {
            foreach ($innerCell->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a )
            {
               echo '<br><a href="'.GetMainBaseFromURL($url).$a->getAttribute('href').'">'.$a->nodeValue.'</a>';

              foreach ($a->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img )
                 echo '<br><a href="'.GetMainBaseFromURL($url).$a->getAttribute('href').'"> <img src="'.GetMainBaseFromURL($url).$img->getAttribute('src').'"></a>';
            }        
        }
      }
   }

   echo "</td>";  
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Then how can i print as it is html table in my web page using php dom document.
I am new in php dom.

Thank you.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What did not work? Are you getting any error?

Comment: Not getting errors but it prints only inner html table data, not  printing outer data which are inside the outer table but outside the inner html tables.

Comment: Then what i have to write for this? The data for first tr is not printing.

Comment: I added an answer showing how you can reduce your code dramatically by using xpath to get the elements you're interested in. Most of the traversing you do should not be necessary. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreach loop iterates 17 just because you have 17  tags in the HTML code you posted.
Actually the $rows = $table->getElementsByTagName("tr"); extracts any  tag at any depth in the tree.

To get only the two outer  you can do something like

$tbody = $table->childNodes;

$outerTr = $tbody->childNodes;

An the iterate on $outerTr

You can also build an Xpath expression to get only the two outer

I did not test yout code however, in the others foreach, keep in mind the same problem of getElementsByTagName("tr") (or other tags td,a ..)

Comment: Thanks you ab_dev86, Your nice communication has solved my problem :)

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByTagName` works on the whole document. The document has 17 `tr` elements, so it will return them all regardless where those are placed.

As you want to look for specific `tr` elements, or more specifically for images inside a specific table, I suggest you let xpath do most of the work:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);

$nodes =$xpath->query("//table[@id='machine']/tbody/tr/td/div/a/img");

echo 'Found ', $nodes->length, ":\n";

foreach($nodes as $node)
{
    $img = $node;
    $a = $node->parentNode;
    $aHref = $a->getAttribute('href');
    $imgSrc = $img->getAttribute('src');
    printf("Element:\n + href: %s;\n +- src: %s\n\n", $aHref, $imgSrc);
}
```

This will list 3 elements already (not 2). You need to further on decide which ones to drop, but this should make it more easy. [Demo](http://codepad.org/ogEIGM4a) & Output:

```
Found 3:
Element:
 + href: /photos.php?id=7135&p=1;
 +- src: /class/class_Image.php?load=cGhvdG9zL0ExMTk0LmpwZ3wyNTB8MjUwfDF8

Element:
 + href: /photos.php?id=7135&p=2;
 +- src: /class/class_Image.php?load=cGhvdG9zL0ExMTk0XzEuanBnfDI1MHwyNTB8MXw=

Element:
 + href: /machine-print.php?id=7135;
 +- src: http://www.sterlingmachinery.com/images/quick_quote.jpg
```

Another tip: First normalize your data into a structure like an array. You can then use your array to generate the output. That done you can separate the parsing from the output which will make it more easy for you to achieve your goals.

- Parse the document into an array.
- Modify values as you need them in that array (e.g. `GetMainBaseFromURL`).
- Generate the output based on the array.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to copy the table you can do this:

```
<?php
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->validateOnParse = true;
$xml->loadHTMLFile($url);

$table = $xml->getElementById('machine');
echo $xml->saveXML($table);
?>
```